# Unable to publish teams package from Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I wanted to use the Graph API to publish a teams app package to our organization with this endpoint
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsapp-publish?view=graph-rest-1.0

When I try to do

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/
Authorization : Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi...
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Length: 4802
```

and my body contains the zip package, I get a 403 error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Failed to execute AuthService backend request GetSkypeTokenRequest. Workload Unknown. Request Url: https://authsvc-server.teams.microsoft.com/v1.0/authz, Request Method: POST, Response Status Code: Forbidden, Response Headers: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains\r\nDate: Tue, 22 Dec 2020 09:43:25 GMT\r\nServer: Kestrel\r\n, Reason Phrase: Forbidden"
    }
}
```

My token has the scope Directory.ReadWrite.All so it might not be a right issue.
My zip package is OK, because it works when i upload it to my organisation from Teams.

Also, the endpoint
GET /appCatalogs/teamsApps/
and DELETE /appCatalogs/teamsApps/{id} works as well.

Any idea what this issue means and how to correct it ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you specify Content length in the request header?   https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeBVS.png

Comment: Yes it is added with postman. I edited my post to add this header in the sample.

Comment: Are you a global administrator?

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.